# Автоматизированный перебор ключей объектов JS

Tags: javascript

Есть JSON объект входных данных с известными нумерованными ключами

```
inputData {

    src1Tm : "719 69 54 29 0x13",
    src2Tm : "720 70 55 30 0x14",
    src3Tm : "721 71 56 31 0x15",
    src4Tm : "722 72 57 32 0x16",
    src5Tm : "723 73 58 33 0x17",
    ....

}
```

Ключей таких много, хочется перебирать их генерируя их имена в цикле.

Но если `src_data[i] = inputData.src1Tm;` возвращает `"719 69 54 29 0x13"`
то почему-то `finder = "src2Tm"; src_data[i] = inputData.finder;` возвращает "undefined"

Прошу помощи - как перебрать нумерованные ключи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда через переменную хотите обратиться к определенному полю объекта нужно использовать квадратные скобки:

```js
var inputData={ 
src1Tm : "719 69 54 29 0x13", 
src2Tm : "720 70 55 30 0x14", 
src3Tm : "721 71 56 31 0x15", 
src4Tm : "722 72 57 32 0x16", 
src5Tm : "723 73 58 33 0x17"}
var finder='src4Tm';
src_data=inputData[finder];
console.log(src_data);
```